# SQL Server Replication - New stored procedures

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, replication

Is there any way that when setting up replication between 2 servers instead of specifying each stored procedure as an article to be replicated, you could actually just replicate ALL stored procedures/user functions?

For example I run replication to a secondary server just so I have an active backup server. As we develop the application and add new stored procedures to the primary server these are not replicated unless we add the new articles into the replication job, this obviously requires additional work to be completed.

Does anybody know of a shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut -  you have to add the new article to replication explicitly. If you are just using this for backup, have you considered log shipping or database mirroring? That may be more "automatic" for you in that you'll get all tables, users, procs, functions, etc. and you don't have to remember to add a table or proc to the replication solution.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll take a look at Database Mirroring - It sounds like a better match for what we are trying to achieve.